# RegEx To Match Last "Word" Containing Any Number

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match the last "word" of a string that contains numbers. Basically, I want to match any characters after the final (space) of the string if any of them are a number.

In my particular case and as an example I'm trying to extract season/episode from a TV show RSS feed. If I have: `Show Name 12x4` or `Show Name 2013-04-12` I wish to match `12x4` and `2013-04-12`.

I started with a last word regex (`[^ ]*$`) but some shows don't have a episode or date (`Show Name`) so I wish to make my regex more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this regex:

```
/[\w\-]+$/
```

Sometimes regex is just not enough, or it gets more complicated... Try splitting the string first:

```
$str = 'Show Name 12x4';
$lastWord = array_pop(explode(' ', $str));

if (preg_match('/(?=\d)/', $lastWord)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: elclanrs: functions the same as my current regex @Twisted1919: close, but what if the show name contains a number?

Comment: @Twisted1919: It's still matching improperly, ie: `Doctor Who (` `2005) - Cold War 7x8`

Comment: Where are the strings coming from? Why `Doctor Who ( 2005)`. Why the space there? Do you have control over this?

Comment: My last try, i think @elclanrs solution is fine enough!
([\d\w\-]+)$

Comment: Try with the lookahead I just posted `(?=\d)`.

Comment: @elclanrs: There is no extra space. The full string would be `Doctor Who (2005) - Cold War 7x8`. Another example could be `Doctor Who  2005 Cold War 7x8` where I wouldn't want to match after/including 2005. But yes, I agree that regex probably isn't enough.

Comment: Then I think this solution should work by splitting the last word... Did it fail?

Comment: hmm, it should also work with my last regex: ([\d\w\-]+)$ I tested with Dr Who example and with the ones from the question and works just fine.

Comment: @Twisted1919 Yes those work but what if there is no number in the last "word"? It still matches the last word unfortunately, ie. it produces `BBC The Blood of the` `Rose`.

Comment: @tenub yeah, that's why i tend to believe the solution elclanrs gave will work just fine :)